# CodeBlocks function arguments autocompletion shortcut

Tags: c++, autocomplete, codeblocks

[image: Screenshot]

This is very easy question... I tried so many shortcuts, I tried googling it, and still nothing... How can I accept this suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the tab key while the autocomplete is showing should work.

This Link mentions hitting Tab to accept a suggestion as well(See Section 2):

http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs333/website-latest/Labs/usingCodeBlocks1/page/usingCodeBlocks1.html

"Pause a moment and notice that a box pops up suggesting a possible completion for this variable name. Hit Tab to accept this suggestion."

Here's another link covering Code::Blocks controls:

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Keyboard_Shortcuts

Hope this helps

Comment: What programming environment/IDE are you using? The tab key works for me in Visual Studio.

Comment: It's CodeBlocks, as maintained in title and tags ;)

Comment: Does the Tab key work for accepting other suggestions made by the autocomplete and just not this particular one, or has the tab key never worked for you?

Comment: Suggestion on variables' names and suggestion of method arguments are different things in C::B. It's strange, but it seems that you **cannot** "accept" the suggestion I'm talking about. Though, there are other ways C::B can help you with defining methods. I'll answer my question when I'll be sure. Thank you very much for your research.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl+Shift+Space` in brackets.